# Argument error for text/image post argument can't contain nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments

The error I am getting is this - `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty.`
This is the code in question:

```
<%= form_for @text_post do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for @image_post do |f| %>
```

Here is my code for **image post controller action**

```
class ImagePostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @image_post = ImagePost.new
  end

  def create 
    @image_post = current_user.image_posts.build(image_post_params)
    if @image_post.save
      redirect_to post_path(@image_post),
      notice: "Post created!"
    else
      render :new, alert: "Error creating post."
    end
  end

  def update
    @image_post = current_user.image_posts.find(params[:id])
    if @image_post.update(image_post_params)
       redirect_to post_path(@image_post), 
      notice: "Post updated!"
    else
      render :edit, alert: "Error updating post."
    end
  end

  private

  def image_post_params
    params.require(:image_post).permit(:title, :url, :body)
  end
end
```

The text post controller is the same code except the `text` is substituted for `image`.
I clearly have the image and text posts defined so I'm not sure why I am getting this error. Anybody have any ideas???

Comment: where and how did you define `@text_post`?

Comment: On which view page you have `<%= form_for @text_post do |f| %>`?

Comment: @image_post = ImagePost.new; raise @image_post; is it even nil?  pretty sure you mess up templates and routes.

Comment: Are you getting this for new and edit or just edit? If the latter - it's because you haven't defined an edit method in your controller.